# SharePoint 2010 RSS Enabled in Central Admin not showing link in Site Settings

Tags: rss, sharepoint-2010

So, we're using SharePoint 2010. Site is accessed via https.

In Central Admin -> Web App -> General Settings, RSS is enabled.

When I go to Site Collection -> Site Settings -> Site Administration there is no link for RSS. What gives?

I'm thinking this has to do with using NTLM vs. Kerberos.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you resolved this? I dont see any reason for not showing it up. ManageWeb,AddAndCustomizePages permissions are required in order to show it up.

Comment: No joy yet. I have local admin and all admin rights within SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Ok....so when somebody TELLS you you have Site Collection Admin privileges....go look yourself just to be sure.

That's all it was. I wasn't give Site Collection Admin privileges....DAG NABBIT!!!!